InternalServiceError while trying to post though a form in xamarin Android
i'm facing some issues regarding my API in xamarin forms, i configured everything but it doesn't work
in the form (running the app on my physical android phone) and it says Exception : InternalServerError
MainPage.xaml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TEST.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="IdMarqueEntry" Placeholder="Enter Id Marque" />
        <Entry x:Name="NomMarqueEntry" Placeholder="Enter Nom Marque" />
        <Button Text="Submit" Clicked="OnSubmitClicked" />
        <Label x:Name="ResultLabel" Text="Result will be displayed here" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>


MainPage.xaml.cs :
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Entities; // Use the namespace where your Marque class is defined
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TEST
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.x.x:5050/api/");
        }

        private async void OnSubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var marque = new Marque
            {
                IdMarque = int.Parse(IdMarqueEntry.Text),
                NomMarque = NomMarqueEntry.Text
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(marque);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            try
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("your", content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    ResultLabel.Text = "Marque added successfully!";
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultLabel.Text = $"Error: {response.StatusCode}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = $"Exception: {ex.Message}";
            }
        }
    }
}


App.xaml.cs :
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Services;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Data;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Services.Services;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Data.UnitOfWork;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Data.Repositories;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Repositories;

namespace TEST
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        // Static property to hold the service provider
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Setup dependency injection
            ConfigureServices();

            // Set the main page as a navigation page containing MainPage
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        private void ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            var connectionString = "Server=192.168.x.x\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;";

    // Register DbContext from the data layer with the direct connection string
    services.AddDbContext<PFAG1_2CarsDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            // Register UnitOfWork and other services if needed
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddScoped<IMarqueService, MarqueService>();

            // Register repositories
            services.AddScoped<IAssuranceRepository, AssuranceRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICategorieRepository, CategorieRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyAssuranceRepository, CompanyAssuranceRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompteRepository, CompteRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IControleTechniqueRepository, ControleTechniqueRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IInterventionRepository, InterventionRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IMarqueRepository, MarqueRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IModelRepository, ModelRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPrestationRepository, PrestationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();

            // Build the service provider
            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}


appsettings.json :
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=192.168.x.x\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Encrypt=False;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApiBaseUrl": "https://192.168.x.x:5050/api/"
}


i tried in postman and my browser and it works just fine, even in my phone's browser

YourController.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Entities;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Repositories;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class YourController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMarqueService _marqueService;

        public YourController(IMarqueService marqueService)
        {
            _marqueService = marqueService;
        }

        // GET: api/marque
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Marque>>> GetMarques()
        {
            try
            {
                var marques = await _marqueService.GetAllMarques();
                return Ok(marques);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // GET: api/marque/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Marque>> GetMarque(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var marque = await _marqueService.GetMarqueById(id);
                if (marque == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Ok(marque);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // POST: api/marque
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Marque>> PostMarque(Marque marque)
        {
            try
            {
                var newMarque = await _marqueService.CreateMarque(marque);
                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetMarque), new { id = newMarque.IdMarque }, newMarque);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // PUT: api/marque/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutMarque(int id, Marque marque)
        {
            try
            {
                await _marqueService.UpdateMarque(new Marque { IdMarque = id }, marque);
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // DELETE: api/marque/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteMarque(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                await _marqueService.DeleteMarqueById(id);
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


it's a server error, that means you need to look at your server code.  Check the logs, or debug it, etc

@Jason i'm sorry but ... which code is it?

The code running on your server.  Whatever endpoint your app is connecting to

@Jason Is it the files in Web.API like Startup.cs? Program.cs? Controller.cs?

I have no idea what your service looks like, what language it is written in, etc.  All I can tell you is that are trying to POST to /api/your and it is returning an error.  So I would suggest starting there.  Or check the logs as I already suggested

imma share a picture of the structure of the Web.API

@Jason i shared the structure of my project

you need to debug the controller endpoint that your client is connecting to.  That is what is returning the error.  I'm not sure how many times I need to repeat that

@Jason ok i will, what confused me is the fact all my requests work on postman, browser's phone and my pc's browser, but not in the app.
I'll try
